# How to understand this threading issue with a dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

I wrote a simple thread adding values to a dictionary from many other parts of the project:

```
public void AddValue(int kid, int vid)
{
    if(!dic.ContainsKey(kid)) dic.Add(kid, new List<int>());
    dic[kid].Add(vid);
}
```

When I ran the code, sometimes it'll show that certain key ID does not exist in the dictionary, I figured that's because different threads are "fighting for it".

But then again, in theory, shouldn't multiple threads fighting for `if(!dic.ContainsKey(kid)) dic.Add(kid, new List<int>());` instead since when different threads enter the method without initiating the dictionary should all satisfy the if condition and attempt to `Add` the key, thus the error should be "The key is already present in the dictionary" instead?

How could one pass the "if" check and still not initiate the key yet?

PS. I'm aware of the `AutoResetEvent` and probably could make it works without any error, I just don't understand how and why the "if" statement could be bypassed.

Comment: Why would you expect all other threads suddenly pausing when one thread is evaluating `!dic.ContainKey(kid)` and won't continue until that thread finished executing `dic.Add(kid, new List<int>());` or `dic[kid].Add(vid);`? Why would they?

Comment: Your assumption clearly is that if one thread concludes evaluating `!dic.ContainKey(kid)` that no other thread is being able to access and modify the dictionary before that first thread has executed either `dic.Add(kid, new List<int>())` or `dic[kid].Add(vid)`. Where is this assumption coming from?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Probably because when other threads enter the method, `!dic.ContainKey(kid)` should be true "to them" too? Regardless of what the first thread is doing?

Comment: The thing is, a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> is not thread-safe. That means whenever one thread is executing code of the (inner private) dictionary implementation, and another thread is also executing code of the dictionary at the same time, and either or both change the inner state of the dictionary, the behavior is undefined, and depending on how exactly the race condition(s) play out, unexpected and on the surface unexplainable behaviors might emerge.

Comment: Do you have working example that intermittently recreates the problem, including your "thread initiating" code?

Comment: When you use something from multiple threads which was not explicitly designed to be accessed from multiple threads - literally anything can happen. Add might require resizing of dictionary internal structures, and another thread might observe dictionary in broken state while that resize happens, for example. Today you have this exception, tomorrow there will be another one, and the other day you won't have any exceptions at all but code instead will do the wrong thing. Just never do that.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, no. And if you would have spent five seconds looking at the existing answers, you would know. Please also ask the other commenters to post their comments as answer and don't just single me out.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, because it would be more or less a duplicate of Roman's answer, which came a couple minutes before i posted the comment you referred to. Then Wanderer's answer, while posted much later than my comment, still posted earlier than your comment response to me. I don't see the need to write essentially duplicate answers.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I can answer that because I also often ignore them. Often question is duplicate and I'm quite certain in that but too lazy to search for it. Another reason - answer should meet certain quality criteria (in my opinion), so it takes more time to write an answer. So often it's not about writing comment or answer - it's about writing comment or nothing at all. But comment might still help the person asking the question, so I prefer that, even if it doesn't align with some guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is [an example that recreates your problem](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fIYT15),

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static readonly IDictionary<int, IList<int>> dic = 
        new Dictionary<int, IList<int>>();
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Enumerable
            .Range(1, 1000000)
            .AsParallel()
            .AsUnordered()
            .ForAll(i => AddValue(i % 100, i));
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Count: {dic.Sum(p => p.Value.Count)}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Total Distinct Count: {dic.SelectMany(p => p.Value).Distinct().Count()}");
    }
    
    public static void AddValue(int kid, int vid)
    {
        if(!dic.ContainsKey(kid))
            dic.Add(kid, new List<int>());
        dic[kid].Add(vid);
    }
}
```

This throws exceptions with messages like,

```
"The given key 'n' was not present in the dictionary"
```

This is happening because the implementation of `Dictionary<T>` is not thread-safe. When `Add` is called but, before it returns, there is a short window when the result of `ContainsKey` differs from the result of the index accessor `[key]`.

This is okay in non-concurrent, single-threaded code, its probably a more optimal implementation. The caller won't use the index accessor until after `Add` has returned.

However, in concurrent code, running on multiple threads, imagine thread A calls `Add`, and now we are in the short window where the results of `ContainsKey` and the index accessor `[key]` differ, then thread B calls `ContainsKey` and tries to access the value, the Exception is thrown.

Other times you'll get,

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

or

```
"An item with the same key has already been added. Key: n"
```

on occasion, the code will run without exception but in the output you'll get two different numbers, neither of which are equal to the expected `1000000`.

All these problems are because both [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0#thread-safety) and [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0#thread-safety) are not thread safe.

---

If we [change the code to](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TTbauT),

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentQueue<int>> dic =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentQueue<int>>();
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Enumerable
            .Range(1, 1000000)
            .AsParallel()
            .AsUnordered()
            .ForAll(i => AddValue(i % 100, i));
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Count: {dic.Sum(p => p.Value.Count)}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Total Distinct Count: {dic.SelectMany(p => p.Value).Distinct().Count()}");
    }
    
    public static void AddValue(int kid, int vid)
    {
        dic.GetOrAdd(kid, _ => new ConcurrentQueue<int>()).Enqueue(vid);
    }
}
```

Everything works as anticipated.

Of course, [for this trivial example, you'd be better off keeping it simple](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fIYT15).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dic = Enumerable
            .Range(1, 1000000)
            .GroupBy(i => i % 100)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Count: {dic.Sum(p => p.Value.Count)}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Total Distinct Count: {dic.SelectMany(p => p.Value).Distinct().Count()}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is still not thread-safe: `dic.Add` will throw if two threads pass `ContainsKey` check at the same time. Good example of how using thread-safe collections does not automatically make code thread safe.

Comment: Also, in documentation of `ConcurrentDictionary` it is stated: "However, members accessed through one of the interfaces the ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> implements, including extension methods, are not guaranteed to be thread safe". You are accessing methods through `IDictionary` interface. I believe they are safe anyway but still good to not assume something and just trust documentation.

Comment: I would look at the implementation of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add()` but I can't access GitHub from my current location.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2#thread-safety) class is not thread-safe. This means that it is expected to be used by one thread at a time. Multiple threads are allowed to interact with the class sequentially, but not concurrently. Otherwise, the behavior of the class is undefined. This means that there is no defined behavior for this class. Microsoft does not provide documentation about the various ways that the class might misbehave, nor provides help through the forums, nor acknowledges any undesirable behavior as a bug. If you use Microsoft's products incorrectly, you are on your own.

You could try and study how the class behaves when it is misused, but it is unlikely to be a good investment of your time. The behavior is dependent on the internal details of the implementation, and these details might change in the next version of the .NET runtime. So unless you have installed defective software on a machine that can't be updated, and it's critical to obtain insights about how the software might misbehave in the next mission of the Mars rover or something, it's far more productive to learn how to write correct multithreaded code, and fix the existing bugs of your application. Here is an online learning resource: [Threading in C# - Thread Safety](https://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Thread_Safety) by Joseph Albahari.

The vast majority of the mutable .NET classes are like the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, they are not thread-safe. Most thread-safe classes exist in the [`System.Threading`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading) and [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent) namespaces. Classes that are immutable, like the collections in the [`System.Collections.Immutable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable) namespace, are also thread-safe. A thread-safe class can be used by multiple threads concurrently without synchronization, and the integrity of its internal state is maintained. Using thread-safe classes usually helps at writing correct multithreaded code, but it's not a panacea. It is easy to write defective code, infested by race conditions, if you use thread-safe classes incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use `Dictionary<>`. It is not thread safe. A `Dictionary` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified (not your case), so you'd to use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is not thread-safe to solve this you can use `ConcurrentDictionary` or `lock` so that only one thread can perform the insertion operations.

Without `lock` or `ConcurrentDictionary` it'll create a race condition between multiple threads which will be difficult to debug.

Example: You can use a lock object based on your requirements, here I'm just using `dic` as a lock object.

```
 public void AddValue(int kid, int vid)
 {
        lock (dic)
        {
            if (!dic.ContainsKey(kid)) dic.Add(kid, new List<int>());
            dic[kid].Add(vid);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what actually did happen when you ran your program, but here's a thing that *could* happen:

```
thread A                               thread B
Enters AddValue(5,17)                     -
calls dic.ContainsKey(5)               Enters AddValue(5,12)
gets result, false                     calls dic.ContainsKey(5)
calls new List<int>()                  gets result, false
adds empty list A as dic[5]            calls new List<int>()
adds 17 to previously empty list A     adds empty list B as dic[5],
   -                                       overwriting list A
   -                                   adds 12 to previously empty list B
```

End result, after both calls have finished, the list, `dic[5]`, contains only one number, `12`.

---

Here's a worse thing that could happen:

```
thread A                               thread B
Enters AddValue(2,42)                     -
calls dic.ContainsKey(2)                  -
gets result, false                        -
calls new List<int>()                     -
calls dic.add(5,...new list...)        Enters AddValue(7,99)
    in-process of mutating dic         calls dic.ContainsKey(7)
    still in process                       encounters corrupt data structure
    returns                                returns wrong result or maybe
returns                                    crashes the program
   -                                   ...
```

End results; thread B could wipe out the existing list for kid=7 because `dic.ContainsKey(7)` gave the wrong answer, or thread B may have attempted to call `dic[7].add(99)` when `dic[7]` is null (same reason), or program could have crashed within `dic.ContainsKey(7)`.